# SQL: using row relative percent value by multiplying it's base value to get dimension

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a challenges. I have in one db table base value colored in blue. This line account and entity information another "cost object". I need to now calculate first total sum by cost object and then calculate row relative amount by prd, cost_object, account, entity. This case # 1 is pretty straightforward to implement by using window functions.

But I have case # 2 where joining rule and sum calculating should be taken on next level.

My question is how to buld SQL which handles both scenarios?

[image]

Comment: Union all might be the command you are after

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi sorry that base information missing. I’am using IBM Netezza as DBMS.